# Adding ScrollPanel to CellTable

Tags: java, gwt

i want to make celltable with scrollpanel on my gwt with uibinder, but can't get this scrollpanel to shown. I tried to add scrollPanel to ui.xml file and within add this celltable:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
  <table style='width:100%;'>
   <tr>
      <td valign='top'>
        <c:CellTable pageSize='10' styleName="cellTable" ui:field='Source'></c:CellTable>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align='center'>
        <c:SimplePager  ui:field='simplePager' location='CENTER'></c:SimplePager>
      </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

but it doesn't show any scrollbar, i tried use datagrid instead of celltable withtin docklayoutpanel like hier:

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel
unit="EM">
<!-- DataGrid. -->
<g:center>
  <c:DataGrid
    ui:field='dataGrid' />
</g:center>
```

but get nothing at all to displayed on the gui, nothing.
Can someone please suggest me how to add scrollpanel to celltable in my ui.xml file?

EDIT:

```
 <g:HTMLPanel>
  <table style='width:100%;'>
   <tr>
      <td valign='top'>
**<g:ScrollPanel>
        <c:CellTable pageSize='10' styleName="cellTable" ui:field='Source'></c:CellTable>
</g:ScrollPanel>**
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align='center'>
        <c:SimplePager  ui:field='simplePager' location='CENTER'></c:SimplePager>
      </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Comment: add `CellTable` or `DataGrid` in `<g:ScrollPanel>`

Comment: do you mean so? i edited my post, added celltable within csrollpanel? if yes i did it already so, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the scroll to appear. You will have to define a height on the scroll panel.

```
<g:ScrollPanel height="500px">
    <c:CellTable pageSize='10' styleName="cellTable" ui:field='Source'></c:CellTable>
</g:ScrollPanel>
```